# PHP copy multiple elements from an XML file to another XML file

Tags: php, xml, dom

I recieve an XML file that's exported from a business accounting application that contains sales data for a given peiod.

Problem is, there are tons of elements in the XML data that I don't need. I'm tryin to pick only the one's I need, and write them to a sperate XML file using PHP, so they can be upoaded to MySql in the next step.

How can I pick out only the elements I need? I've tried using PHP DOM `getElementsByTagName` but cannot figure how to get multiple elements and all elements with those names from the XML file in one go.

The [sample XML file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rFo_M_z0Nttv7YaIbREAqCjpmKFPQhd4) is just a portion of the original XML file. The original runs to 10K+ lines.

I need only these, and all of them from the XML file (there are several):

```
DATE
PARTYLEDGERNAME
LEDGERNAME
AMOUNT
STOCKITEMNAME
RATE
BILLEDQTY
AMOUNT
```

So the desired output looks like this:

```
<DATE>20180602</DATE>

<PARTYLEDGERNAME>ACME</PARTYLEDGERNAME>

<LEDGERNAME>CGST @ 9%</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT>3.05</AMOUNT>

<LEDGERNAME>SGST @ 9%</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT>3.05</AMOUNT>

<LEDGERNAME>CGST @ 2.5%</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT>1.19</AMOUNT>

<LEDGERNAME>SGST @ 2.5%</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT>1.19</AMOUNT>

<LEDGERNAME>NGST Sales</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT>2998.82</AMOUNT>

<STOCKITEMNAME>Diesel</STOCKITEMNAME>
<RATE>69.74/Ltr</RATE>
<BILLEDQTY>43.000 Ltr</BILLEDQTY>
<AMOUNT>2998.82</AMOUNT>

<STOCKITEMNAME>Cleenol (500 ML)</STOCKITEMNAME>
<RATE>33.90/Pcs</RATE>
<BILLEDQTY>1 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
<AMOUNT>33.90</AMOUNT>

<STOCKITEMNAME>Polishing Cloth</STOCKITEMNAME>
<RATE>23.80/Pcs</RATE>
<BILLEDQTY>2 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
<AMOUNT>47.60</AMOUNT>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your output structure is flat, you can use SimpleXML to load the file and then just scan through the structure and if the element name matches a list of the fields you want then just add them to an output XML document.

```
$file = "voucher.xml";
$in = simplexml_load_file($file);
$out = new SimpleXMLElement("<ENVELOPE />");  // You need a base element
$fields = ["DATE",
    "PARTYLEDGERNAME",
    "LEDGERNAME",
    "AMOUNT",
    "STOCKITEMNAME",
    "RATE",
    "BILLEDQTY",
    "AMOUNT"];

function extractFields ( $in, $out, $fields ) {
    foreach ( $in as $name => $element ) {
        if ( in_array($name, $fields) ) {
            $out->addChild($name, (string)$element);
        }
        if ( $element->count() > 0 ){
            extractFields($element, $out, $fields);
        }
    }
}

extractFields( $in, $out, $fields );
echo $out->asXML();
```

The recursive calls to `extractFields()` allows the code to repeatedly go through any child data and extract the values as needed.  You can change the base element to anything you want, but it is needed for XML.

The output with your test data is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ENVELOPE>
    <DATE>20180602</DATE>
    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>ACME</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
    <LEDGERNAME>ACME</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>-3088.80</AMOUNT>
    <LEDGERNAME>CGST @ 9%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>3.05</AMOUNT>
    <LEDGERNAME>SGST @ 9%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>3.05</AMOUNT>
    <LEDGERNAME>CGST @ 2.5%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>1.19</AMOUNT>
    <LEDGERNAME>SGST @ 2.5%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>1.19</AMOUNT>
    <STOCKITEMNAME>Diesel</STOCKITEMNAME>
    <RATE>69.74/Ltr</RATE>
    <AMOUNT>2998.82</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 43.000 Ltr</BILLEDQTY>
    <AMOUNT>2998.82</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 43.000 Ltr</BILLEDQTY>
    <LEDGERNAME>NGST Sales</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>2998.82</AMOUNT>
    <STOCKITEMNAME>Cleenol (500 ML)</STOCKITEMNAME>
    <RATE>33.90/Pcs</RATE>
    <AMOUNT>33.90</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 1 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
    <AMOUNT>33.90</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 1 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
    <LEDGERNAME>Sales @ 18%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>33.90</AMOUNT>
    <STOCKITEMNAME>Polishing Cloth</STOCKITEMNAME>
    <RATE>23.80/Pcs</RATE>
    <AMOUNT>47.60</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 2 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
    <AMOUNT>47.60</AMOUNT>
    <BILLEDQTY> 2 Pcs</BILLEDQTY>
    <LEDGERNAME>Sales @ 5%</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>47.60</AMOUNT>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP SimpleXML to read a specifically data:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp

After you can write these data to new XML file:

```html
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
$xml_track = $xml->createElement("Track");
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );

$xml->save("/tmp/test.xml");
```

Comment: This does not work considering how the XML file is structured. Which is why I'm trying to get at each element with a specific name.